# Why will these strings not be quoted by psycopg2 for the query?

Tags: django, django-orm, psycopg2

Writing an app with django, using the psycopg2 engine.  It doesn't always seem to want to quote my strings.  Here is a test case:

```
>>> from pypvs.search.models import Addr2zip
>>> kwargs = {
...     'street_name__iexact': 'Common Ground',
...     'state_id__iexact': 'MT',
... }
>>> addrMatch = Addr2zip.objects.extra(
...     where = ['ctystate.zip5 = addr2zip.zip5 AND ctystate.city_name = \'%s\'' % 'Philipsburg'],
...     tables = ['ctystate', 'addr2zip']
... ).filter(**kwargs).order_by('zip5', 'street_name', 'primary_address_low', 'secondary_address_low')
>>> print addrMatch.query
SELECT "addr2zip"."addr2zip_id", "addr2zip"."zip5", "addr2zip"."zip4_low", "addr2zip"."zip4_high", "addr2zip"."street_direction", "addr2zip"."street_name", "addr2zip"."street_suffix", "addr2zip"."street_post_direction", "addr2zip"."primary_address_low", "addr2zip"."primary_address_high", "addr2zip"."primary_address_parity", "addr2zip"."secondary_address", "addr2zip"."secondary_address_low", "addr2zip"."secondary_address_high", "addr2zip"."secondary_address_parity", "addr2zip"."state_id", "addr2zip"."county_code", "addr2zip"."municipality_key", "addr2zip"."urbanization_key", "addr2zip"."record_type" FROM "addr2zip" , "ctystate" WHERE (ctystate.zip5 = addr2zip.zip5 AND ctystate.city_name = Philipsburg AND UPPER("addr2zip"."state_id"::text) = UPPER(MT)  AND UPPER("addr2zip"."street_name"::text) = UPPER(Common Ground) ) ORDER BY "addr2zip"."zip5" ASC, "addr2zip"."street_name" ASC, "addr2zip"."primary_address_low" ASC, "addr2zip"."secondary_address_low" ASC
```

What could be the reason that these strings are not quoted?  For instance, 'Common Ground':

```
AND UPPER("addr2zip"."street_name"::text) = UPPER(Common Ground)
```

Not sure if the problem is in my implementation, psycopg2, or the django ORM.  I'd appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str(query)` only returns an approximative representation of the query. Are you trying to pass it to the database?

The query issued with `iexact` seems correct with Django 1.2.3. The above would result in `WHERE UPPER("addr2zip"."street_name"::text) = UPPER(E'Common Ground')`. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To get the query to be executed, use something like:

```
from django.db import DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
queryset.query.get_compiler(DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS).as_sql()
```

Answer (score 0):

But you just pasted it like that yourself:

```
where = ['ctystate.zip5 = addr2zip.zip5 AND ctystate.city_name = %s' % 'Philipsburg'],
```

so you got query string constructed with syntax error:

```
AND ctystate.city_name = Philipsburg
```

Comment: I get that one.  But see the example I used in the original post for 'street_name'.